# PyQGIS seems to be converting dict into QVariant

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins, dictionary

I created a PyQGIS plug in that creates loops over the features on a layer to create the body of an API post request. However, when I try to run that API call I get an error telling me the json parameter is not a "dict" but rather a QVariant. Here is my code:

```
def createFeatures(body, token):
    if not isinstance(token, dict):
        token = {'token':token, "content-type": "application/json"}

    url = f'https://fibermap.vetro.io/v2/features/'
    print(type(body))
    r = requests.post(url, headers=token, json=body)

    if r.status_code == 201:
        return r.json()['result']
    else:
        msg = r.json()['message']
        msg = f"Failed at creating new features\n\n{msg}\n"
        qgis_popup(msg,f"Error {r.status_code}","Critical")
```

The part I find perplexing is that if the print statement returns `<class 'dict'>`. Yet the next line gives me the following error:

```
WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/RafaelC/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis_to_vetro\qgis_to_vetro.py", line 378, in run
              new_features = createFeatures(body_create, vetroToken)
              File "C:/Users/RafaelC/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis_to_vetro\VetroAPI.py", line 314, in createFeatures
              r = requests.post(url, headers=token, json=body)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 119, in post
              return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
              return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 516, in request
              prep = self.prepare_request(req)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 459, in prepare_request
              hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 317, in prepare
              self.prepare_body(data, files, json)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 467, in prepare_body
              body = complexjson.dumps(json)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 382, in dumps
              return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\simplejson\encoder.py", line 296, in encode
              chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\simplejson\encoder.py", line 378, in iterencode
              return _iterencode(o, 0)
              File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS3~1.16\apps\Python37\lib\site-packages\simplejson\encoder.py", line 273, in default
              o.__class__.__name__)
             TypeError: Object of type QVariant is not JSON serializable
```

Moreover, even if I try to use say `print(json.dumps(body,indent=4))` I get the same error.  I am using QGIS3.16.

Does anyone know what could be happening here?

Comment: Indeed, please share the full traceback

Comment: I have now added the full traceback of the error message

Comment: The error message does not say that body IS a QVariant but that body CONTAINS some QVariant as values. These QVariant probably comes from NULL values in your qgis feature. You need to sanitize your dict before trying to serialize it to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found the problem. The 'body' dictionary had keys whose values were 'NULL'. After removing those, the code runs as expected.